# Smallest trapeziums containing a given convex n-gon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

**Question:** Given a planar convex $n$-gon $C$, to find the smallest area / smallest perimeter trapezium (trapezoid) - a convex quadrilateral with at least one pair of mutually parallel edges - that contains $C$. Can an algorithm linear in n be found?

**Further question:** For which general convex (not necessarily polygonal) shape of $C$ are the orientations (direction of its parallel sides) of the smallest area and smallest perimeter trapezium containers of $C$ most different?

Note: A constrained version of the same questions as above with the trapezium constrained to be isosceles (its non parallel sides being of equal length) could also be considered.

Some further thoughts are recorded at http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/03/non-congruent-tiling-18-and-oriented.html.

Comment: More generally, if $C$ is a trapezium, then the expected answer is $C$ itself.

Comment: Yes. And if C is a triangle, its smallest containing trapezium 'degenerates' into triangle C. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to prove (or disprove) that for minimum area trapezoid, at least one edge of the trapezoid is flush (collinear and overlapping) with an edge of $C$. That would yield a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: Related but doesn't immediately solve your question. From [my own work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03153): Lemma 17.3. The *width* of $C$ is always achieved by (a) one of the supporting lines flush with an edge $e$ of $C$ , and (b) the other line including a vertex that projects onto $e$.

Comment: What is your definition of a trapezium? Two parallel, opposite edges but otherwise no constraints on the sides?

Comment: Yes. No other constraint than a pair of opposite parallel edges. Edited question. Thanks. Moreover, following your first suggestion, it appears that at least one of the non-parallel pair of edges of the *least area* containing trapezoid needs to be flush with an edge of C.

Answer (score 1):

Fix two parallel horizontal lines $L,L'$ touching the convex polygon $C$ at
antipodal points.
If the leftmost vertex $v$ is not exactly halfway between $L,L'$,
then rotating a segment through $v$ in one direction or the other will
decrease area.
If the rightmost vertex $u$ is exactly halfway, then rotating a segment
through $u$ keeps the area fixed.
So, in either case, we can rotate until each of the nonparallel sides is flush
with an edge of $C$, either decreasing or maintaining the area
throughout the rotation.

Therefore, there is always a least-area trapezoid with both nonparallel
sides flush with edges of $C$.

[image: Trapezoid]

This should lead to brute-force $O(n^3)$ algorithm:
choose the two flush edges, and rotate $L,L'$ "calipers" through all antipodal
pairs. I won't try to detail this algorithm because there is likely a
more efficient approach.

Comment: Thanks for the nice proof. A linear algorithm would be even nicer!

Comment: By tilting the left line in figure further in the direction of the arrow, we also see that this lemma *does not* apply as it is to containing trapezoids of minimum perimeter.